# Turbo performance benefit confusion, application teardown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I'm unsure about this last sentence in the first paragraph of the [Turbo docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/introduction).

> A key attraction with traditional single-page applications, when compared with the old-school, separate-pages approach, is the speed of navigation. **SPAs get a lot of that speed from not constantly tearing down the application process**, only to reinitialize it on the very next page.

When this mentions "tearing down the application process", this means the server application process does not get torn down on each request or the browser application process? Does the concept of a browser application process exist in this context?

Comment: It's talking about the browser-side. Imagine using slack, but each time you switched to a different DM, it reloaded the whole page. That'd be a big chuck on JS to re-initialize just because you wanted to see a different conversation.

Comment: "Application process" here is very loose and fast jargon. What they are actually talking about is all the steps of performing a syncronous request which involves unloading the old page (firing any handlers and doing cleanup stuff) and then going through all the steps of rebuilding the DOM from scratch and negotiating all the assets etc that you have to do when loading.